# How can I parse XML doc with Schema 1.1, in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xsd, eclipse-cdt, xerces

How can I validate XML documents with Schema 1.1 in "Eclipse IDE"
OR
How can I validate an XML docs in "Eclipse IDE" by using external Apache xerces parser? (this will resolve my issue as xerces supports Schema 1.1)

Answer (score 1):

Not yet: there is a standing [**bug 204125**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=204125) on that topic:

```
Ed Merks      2009-12-16 12:02:07 EST
```

> Volunteers are warmly welcomed!

As mentioned by Jesper S Møller in December 2009,

> Shouldn't this be split/spun-off into multiple bugs, one for the XSD model and
>   one for any mapping/serialization support for ECore?

So, that bug is related to **[bug 288527](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288527)** "(WTP) [editor] Investigate XML Schema 1.1 support"... with no activity on it yet.

Comment: Thank you VonC but it seems a bit different scenario. Eclipse depends heavily on XML parsing for its internal processing, so changing its default xml parser creates a big risk for whole platform. That is why they people are extraordinary cautious
While I am looking, if possible, to use an external XML parser to parse only my XML docs. So primary question is, is it possible to use more than one XML parser in Eclipse? If I am not wrong, answer is "yes". Then second question would be "how"